# hive metastore read timeout

Tags: hive, hive-metastore

We are using Hive 2.3.3 along with Hadoop 2.7.7 and Spark 2.4.4.

We are using MariaDB as a backend database for Metastore.

The startup of the Metastore service is fine, and I am able to access Hive CLI and perform query operations.  I am not starting up HS2 (to try to isolate the issue).

But after a while, all of the sudden, the Hive Metastore service is stuck and is not responding, even to simple queries `show databases` or `show tables`.

All the tables against which we execute other queries are empty (no partitions created as of now) and this environment is being newly created.

hive.log error file:

```
2020-10-09T18:43:56,971 DEBUG [IPC Client (1223050066) connection to master/10.28.66.65:8020 from hadoopuser] ipc.Client: IPC Client (1223050066) connection to master/10.28.66.65:8020 from hadoopuser: closed
2020-10-09T18:43:56,971 DEBUG [IPC Client (1223050066) connection to master/10.28.66.65:8020 from hadoopuser] ipc.Client: IPC Client (1223050066) connection to master/10.28.66.65:8020 from hadoopuser: stopped, remaining connections 0
2020-10-09T18:53:53,769  WARN [9edaa669-999e-41a9-a7b3-bcee9d6198f4 main] metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient: MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect (1 of 1) after 5s. getAllFunctions
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_all_functions(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3812) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_all_functions(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3800) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getAllFunctions(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2393) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
....


2020-10-09T18:53:58,777  INFO [9edaa669-999e-41a9-a7b3-bcee9d6198f4 main] hive.metastore: Closed a connection to metastore, current connections: 0
2020-10-09T18:53:58,777  INFO [9edaa669-999e-41a9-a7b3-bcee9d6198f4 main] hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://master:9083
2020-10-09T18:53:58,779  INFO [9edaa669-999e-41a9-a7b3-bcee9d6198f4 main] hive.metastore: Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 1
2020-10-09T18:53:58,805  INFO [9edaa669-999e-41a9-a7b3-bcee9d6198f4 main] hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
```

Comment: since you're also loosing connection to your namenode (_connection to master/10.28.66.65:8020 from hadoopuser: closed_) I'd start by looking at your network setup.

Comment: Check how many partitions are there in the table? If it has too many then high chance that timeout happens & also check the `hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout` value?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. The connection to 8020 (yarn master) is not failing. The connection from metastore is failing, which is to the database I guess.   Also the issue happened even without any data in hadoop hence I discounted the issue of partition. Between, I have set the value for hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout to 1800.